# Openstack-Folsom keystone script fail to configure

Tags: openstack, keystone

Based on this link https://github.com/mseknibilel/OpenStack-Folsom-Install-guide/blob/master/OpenStack_Folsom_Install_Guide_WebVersion.rst#openstack-folsom-install-guide , I tried running these scripts but it fails despite me setting the HOST_IP & EXT HOST_IP.
./keystone_basic.sh
./keystone_endpoints_basic.sh

Below is the error log received:-
-keystone:error:unrecognized arguments: service id of 18ea5916544429bed2c84af0303077

I have provide the information such as tenant_name, tenant_id and so on in a source file but it happens to be the script provided does not get recognized by the system. Below are the details of the OS I use.

I created VMs instead of using physical machines. Installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Please advice on how to tackle this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: did you swap in relevant usernames / passwords / tenant names etc?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. After running:

keystone help user-create tenant id appears as follows:

```
Optional arguments:
...
--service_id <service-id>
```

Change --service-id to --service_id with a global replace

```
[Using command line] 
# sed -i 's/--service-id/--service_id/g' /path/to/script.sh
```

restart keystone & It's database entries

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "drop database keystone"
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "create database keystone"
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "grant all privileges on keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'%' identified by 'password'"
mysql -u root -ppassword -e "grant all privileges on keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'localhost' identified by 'password'"
service keystone restart
keystone-manage db_sync
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, AEgrouplabs and thank you for posting not just an answer, but an answer with some examples.